# How to successfully install full Mono Develop IDE on Debian?

Tags: c#, android, linux, mono, debian

I cannot install Mono for .NET on Debian.

I've tried it as here (http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#debian-ubuntu-and-derivatives) and first three commands worked fine. Then I've used 'Usage' section but info there was very general. So I've just executed "sudo apt-get install mono-devel" but it has failed:

root@myusername:~# sudo apt-get install mono-devel
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-devel : Depends: libgdiplus (>= 2.6.7) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-design4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-drawing4.0-cil (>= 3.0.6) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-messaging4.0-cil (>= 2.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-runtime4.0-cil (>= 2.10.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-servicemodel-activation4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-servicemodel-web4.0-cil (>= 3.2.1) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-servicemodel4.0a-cil (>= 3.2.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-web-extensions4.0-cil (>= 2.10.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-web-services4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-web4.0-cil (>= 2.10.3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-system-windows-forms4.0-cil (>= 1.0) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmono-cil-dev (= 4.2.2.30-0xamarin2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Similar thing for "sudo apt-get install monodevelop".

So I've used other method, directly for Debian. I've downloaded file "monodevelop_4.0.12+dfsg-6_all.deb" from here (https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/monodevelop/download). When I run it in Apper Installer, I get:

Error: This package is uninstallable
Cannot install 'libglade2.0-cil'

By the way, for some reason Debian treats Engrampa Archive Manager as default application for deb files.

How can I install full Mono Development IDE and its related packages? I want to work on simple application for Android. I have experience with C# .NET but not with Linux or Android.

Thank you!

Comment: this smell as if you have mixed packages from different versions of Debian, don't do that unless you know what you're doing

Answer (score 0):

The Mono Installation Page actually references packages for Wheezy. If you are on Jessie, you should update it to the following and it should work:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian jessie main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
```

If you're not on "Jessie" (aka Debian 8), substitute the appropriate name for what version you are on.

Then assuming you want the dev package:

```
apt-get install mono-devel
```